# Zoom functionality using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

Current implementation, zooms towards the center of View so items present in the top left corner or the current mouse pointer is not visible when we Zoom it.

I want zoom functionality based on the current mouse pointer so items present on the current mouse pointer zoom towards the center of the view.

Code for Zoom base don center of view area

```
void csGuiView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{

    if ((event->modifiers()&Qt::ControlModifier) == Qt::ControlModifier
        && event->angleDelta().x() == 0)
    {
    QPoint  pos  = event->pos();
    QPointF posf = this->mapToScene(pos);

    double angle = event->angleDelta().y();

    double scalingFactor;

    if(angle > 0)
    {
        scalingFactor = 1 + ( angle / 360 * 0.1);
    }else if (angle < 0)
    {
        scalingFactor = 1 - ( -angle / 360 * 0.1);
    } else
    {
        scalingFactor = 1;
    }

    m_pvtData->m_scale = scalingFactor;

    this->scale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor);

    double w = this->viewport()->width();
    double h = this->viewport()->height();

    double wf = this->mapToScene(QPoint(w-1, 0)).x()
            - this->mapToScene(QPoint(0,0)).x();
    double hf = this->mapToScene(QPoint(0, h-1)).y()
            - this->mapToScene(QPoint(0,0)).y();

    double lf = posf.x() - pos.x() * wf / w;
    double tf = posf.y() - pos.y() * hf / h;

    /* try to set viewport properly */
    this->ensureVisible(lf, tf, wf, hf, 0, 0);


    QPointF newPos = this->mapToScene(pos);


    this->ensureVisible(QRectF(QPointF(lf, tf) - newPos + posf,
                               QSizeF(wf, hf)), 0, 0);

    }

    if ((event->modifiers()&Qt::ControlModifier) != Qt::ControlModifier) {
    QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
    }

    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why this is tagged [tag:qt4]?

Comment: @Scheff I would imagine it means OP uses Qt4...? Do you have a reason to suspect it is not so?

Comment: @hyde I think I can provide a sample but I've Qt5. However, I believe it's not relevant for that sample.

Comment: No specific reason for Tagging qt4

Comment: @Scheff well, I edited the tags then...

Comment: Ah. Just noticed your new tag `QGraphicsView`. In this case, using a `QMatrix` to manage scaling should be fine. I once used `QGraphicsView` in a sample code (for graph rendering) and saw I used `QGraphicsView::fitInView()` and `QGraphicsView::resetMatrix()`. This let me think you may use the built-in matrix - no need to define your own member...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To zoom always centered at mouse pointer – the position of mouse pointer just has to become the origin of scaling.

It sounds that simple but I struggled a bit to prepare a demonstration. (I'm not that good in linear algebra, sorry.) However, I finally got it running.

My sample code `testQWidget-Zoom.cc`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <QtWidgets>

// class for widget to demonstrate zooming
class Canvas: public QWidget {
  // types:
  private:
    struct Geo {
      QRectF rect; QColor color;
      Geo(const QRectF &rect, const QColor &color):
        rect(rect), color(color)
      { }
    };
  // variables:
  private:
    bool _initDone : 1; // flag: true ... sample geo created
    std::vector<Geo> _scene; // contents to render
    QMatrix _mat; // view matrix
  // methods:
  public: 
    // constructor.
    Canvas(): QWidget(), _initDone(false) { }
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Canvas() = default;
    // disabled:
    Canvas(const Canvas&) = delete;
    Canvas& operator=(const Canvas&) = delete;
  private:
    // initializes sample geo
    void init()
    {
      if (_initDone) return;
      _initDone = true;
      // build scene (with NDC i.e. view x/y range: [-1, 1])
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-1.0f, -1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), QColor(0x000000u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.2f, -0.2f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x00ff00u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.8f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff0000u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x0000ffu)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff00ffu)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(0.4f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xffff00u)));
      // get initial scaling
      const int wView = width(), hView = height();
      _mat.scale(wView / 2, hView / 2);
      _mat.translate(1, 1);
    }
  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      init();
      // render
      QPainter qPainter(this);
#if 0 // This scales line width as well:
      qPainter.setMatrix(_mat);
      for (const Geo &geo : _scene) {
        qPainter.setPen(geo.color);
        qPainter.drawRect(geo.rect);
      }
#else // This transforms only coordinates:
      for (const Geo &geo : _scene) {
        qPainter.setPen(geo.color);
        QRectF rect(geo.rect.topLeft() * _mat, geo.rect.bottomRight() * _mat);
        qPainter.drawRect(rect);
      }
#endif // 0
    }
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      //qDebug() << "Wheel Event:"
      //qDebug() << "mouse pos:" << pQEvent->pos();
      // pos() -> virtual canvas
      bool matInvOK = false;
      QMatrix matInv = _mat.inverted(&matInvOK);
      if (!matInvOK) {
        qDebug() << "View matrix not invertible!";
        return;
      }
      QPointF posNDC
        = QPointF(pQEvent->pos().x(), pQEvent->pos().y()) * matInv;
      //qDebug() << "mouse pos (NDC):" << posNDC;
      float delta = 1.0f + pQEvent->angleDelta().y() / 1200.0f;
      //qDebug() << "angleDelta:" << pQEvent->angleDelta().y();
      //qDebug() << "scale factor:" << delta;
      _mat.translate(posNDC.x(), posNDC.y()); // origin to spot
      _mat.scale(delta, delta); // scale
      _mat.translate(-posNDC.x(), -posNDC.y()); // spot to origin
      update();
      pQEvent->accept();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Canvas canvas;
  canvas.resize(512, 512);
  canvas.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

and these three lines are the actual interesting ones (in `Canvas::wheelEvent()`):

```
      _mat.translate(posNDC.x(), posNDC.y()); // origin to spot
      _mat.scale(delta, delta); // scale
      _mat.translate(-posNDC.x(), -posNDC.y()); // spot to origin
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: Snapshot of testQWidget-Zoom - initially]

[image: Snapshot of testQWidget-Zoom - after pointing into red rect and turning the wheel]

The first image is a snapshot of the application just after starting it.

Then I pointed into the center of the red rectangle and turned the wheel slightly. The red rectangle grew around the mouse pointer as intended.

---

**1<sup>st</sup> Update:**

And, this is the updated version which uses screen coordinates directly (instead of converting everything to NDCs):

```
#include <vector>
#include <QtWidgets>

// class for widget to demonstrate zooming
class Canvas: public QWidget {
  // types:
  private:
    struct Geo {
      QRectF rect; QColor color;
      Geo(const QRectF &rect, const QColor &color):
        rect(rect), color(color)
      { }
    };
  // variables:
  private:
    bool _initDone : 1; // flag: true ... sample geo created
    std::vector<Geo> _scene; // contents to render
    QMatrix _mat; // view matrix
  // methods:
  public: 
    // constructor.
    Canvas(): QWidget(), _initDone(false) { }
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Canvas() = default;
    // disabled:
    Canvas(const Canvas&) = delete;
    Canvas& operator=(const Canvas&) = delete;
  private:
    // initializes sample geo
    void init()
    {
      if (_initDone) return;
      _initDone = true;
      const int wView = width(), hView = height();
      // build scene (with NDC i.e. view x/y range: [-1, 1])
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-1.0f, -1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), QColor(0x000000u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.2f, -0.2f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x00ff00u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.8f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff0000u)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(-0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x0000ffu)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff00ffu)));
      _scene.emplace_back(Geo(QRectF(0.4f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xffff00u)));
      // scale geometry to screen coordinates
      QMatrix mat;
      mat.scale(wView / 2, hView / 2);
      mat.translate(1, 1);
      for (Geo &geo : _scene) {
        geo.rect = QRectF(geo.rect.topLeft() * mat, geo.rect.bottomRight() * mat);
      }
    }
  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      init();
      // render
      QPainter qPainter(this);
      qPainter.setMatrix(_mat);
      for (const Geo &geo : _scene) {
        qPainter.setPen(geo.color);
        qPainter.drawRect(geo.rect);
      }
    }
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      //qDebug() << "Wheel Event:";
      //qDebug() << "mouse pos:" << pQEvent->pos();
      float delta = 1.0f + pQEvent->angleDelta().y() / 1200.0f;
      //qDebug() << "angleDelta:" << pQEvent->angleDelta().y();
      //qDebug() << "scale factor:" << delta;
      _mat.translate(pQEvent->pos().x(), pQEvent->pos().y()); // origin to spot
      _mat.scale(delta, delta); // scale
      _mat.translate(-pQEvent->pos().x(), -pQEvent->pos().y()); // spot to origin
      update();
      pQEvent->accept();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Canvas canvas;
  canvas.resize(256, 256);
  canvas.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The relevant three lines didn't change much – the mouse coordinates are applied directly to transformation.

Btw. I changed the rendering – it now scales line width as well as I used

```
      qPainter.setMatrix(_mat);
```

in `Canvas::paintEvent()` instead of transforming all points "manually".

The snapshot shows the application after I pointed into the center of the blue rectangle and turned the mouse wheel:

[image: Snapshot of testQWidget-Zoom - after pointing into blue rect and turning the wheel]

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> Update:**

The suggested matrix manipulation works in a [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) as well:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

// class for widget to demonstrate zooming
class Canvas: public QGraphicsView {
  // methods:
  public: 
    // constructor.
    Canvas() = default;
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Canvas() = default;
    // disabled:
    Canvas(const Canvas&) = delete;
    Canvas& operator=(const Canvas&) = delete;

  protected:

    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      //qDebug() << "Wheel Event:";
      // pos() -> virtual canvas
      QPointF pos = mapToScene(pQEvent->pos());
      //qDebug() << "mouse pos:" << pos;
      // scale from wheel angle
      float delta = 1.0f + pQEvent->angleDelta().y() / 1200.0f;
      //qDebug() << "angleDelta:" << pQEvent->angleDelta().y();
      //qDebug() << "scale factor:" << delta;
      // modify transform matrix
      QTransform xform = transform();
      xform.translate(pos.x(), pos.y()); // origin to spot
      xform.scale(delta, delta); // scale
      xform.translate(-pos.x(), -pos.y()); // spot to origin
      setTransform(xform);
      //qDebug() << "transform:" << xform;
      // force update
      update();
      pQEvent->accept();
    }
};

QRectF toScr(QWidget *pQWidget, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
  const int wView = pQWidget->width(), hView = pQWidget->height();
  const int s = wView < hView ? wView : hView;
  return QRectF(
    (0.5f * x + 0.5f) * s, (0.5f * y + 0.5f) * s,
    0.5f * w * s, 0.5f * h * s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  Canvas canvas;
  canvas.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
  canvas.resize(256, 256);
  canvas.show();
  // prepare scene
  QGraphicsScene qGScene;
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -1.0f, -1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), QColor(0x000000u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.2f, -0.2f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x00ff00u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff0000u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x0000ffu));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff00ffu));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), 0.4f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xffff00u));
  canvas.setScene(&qGScene);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Using a `QGraphicsView` simplifies code as no rendering code is needed – it's already built-in.

As I have not (yet) much experience with `QGraphicsView`, another issue hit me quite hard: The `QGraphicsView` is able to fix the view position automati[cg]ally after a transformation has been applied. In my case, this was rather counter-productive as obviously my transformation and the `QGraphicsView` seemed to "pull" in opposite directions.

Hence, I've learnt my lesson of the day:  [`QGrapicsView::setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#transformationAnchor-prop)
is necessary to switch off this (in my case not-intended) auto-centering.

The other detail I find worth to notice is [`QGraphicsView::mapToScene()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene) which can be used to conveniently convert widget coordinates (e.g. mouse coordinates) to scene space.

[image: snapshot of testQWidget-Zoom after port to QGraphicsView]

Comment: It seems that you hadn't any problem to apply my answer to "your" `QGraphicsView` - I had. Therefore, I needed a little bit longer until I got it running but finally I got. Hence, a 2nd update of my answer.