# How can I move the content of QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am trying to implement a zooming system for my QGraphicsView in Qt. However, I do not wish to use `QGraphicsView::scale()` because I want only certain items to be scaled. When I zoom in, everything looks good (I mean the elements are in the center of the view). When I zoom out, though, everything is anchored at the top left corner. I can zoom in and it will eventually center back, but when I zoom out again, it's still anchored. Here is an illustration of what I mean:

[image: Zoomin in and out]

EDIT: This is what's happening right now on mouse scroll.

This is what I'm currently doing on mouse scroll:

```cpp
for (int y = 0; y < canvasSize[0]; i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < canvasSize[1]; j++)
    {
        pixels[y][x]->setRect(y*zoomLevel, x*zoomLevel, zoomLevel, zoomLevel); // Scaling the items
    }
}
QPointF delta = target_viewport_pos - mouse_event->pos();
if (qAbs(delta.x()) > 5 || qAbs(delta.y()) > 5) {
    target_viewport_pos = mouse_event->pos();
    target_scene_pos = _view->mapToScene(mouse_event->pos());
}
_view->centerOn(target_scene_pos);
QPointF delta_viewport_pos = target_viewport_pos - QPointF(_view->viewport()->width() / 2.0,
                                                           _view->viewport()->height() / 2.0);
QPointF viewport_center = _view->mapFromScene(target_scene_pos) - delta_viewport_pos;
_view->centerOn(_view->mapToScene(viewport_center.toPoint()));
```

The code that moves the view (that I admit I didn't write myself) works really well when I use `QGraphicsView::scale()` but when I use my custom scaling instead, it does nothing. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: FYI: [SO: Zoom functionality using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710623/7478597) and, may be, this: [SO: Zooming in / out on images - QT c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282392/7478597)