# QT - cant make scene move with mouseMove

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I've got simple cpp code. I would like to move QGraphicsScene with mouse move:

```
// MainWindow.cpp code ------------------------------

void MainWindow::initializeMainViewWidget() {
/* some code */
    itemsFrame->setLayout(layout);

    mView = std::make_unique<ui::MainView>();
    layout->addWidget(mView.get());

    mScene = std::make_unique<ui::MainScene>();
    mView->setScene(mScene.get());

    QObject::connect(mScene.get(), &ui::MainScene::openItem, this, &MainWindow::openUpdateItemDialog);

    mView->show();
}

// MainView.cpp code -------------------------------

void MainView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        // Store original position.
        mPos0 = event->position(); //mPos0 is QPointF
        event->accept();
        setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);
        return;
    } else if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        event->ignore();
    }
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}


void MainView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        event->ignore();
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        QPointF trans = event->position() - mPos0;
        mPos0 = event->position();
        event->accept();
        translate(trans.x(), trans.y());
        return;
    }
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

But when I add item by:
addItem(someQGraphicsItem);

Item is shown. I can drag it... but can't move scene with RMB and mouseMove.

Comment: Please, have a loot at [QGraphicsView::transformationAnchor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#transformationAnchor-prop). The default is `AnchorViewCenter`. Hence, the `translate()` might be "auto-corrected" unintendedly. Try to set it to e.g. `QGraphicsView::NoAnchor` (maybe, after initial `mView->show();`). (I once struggled with this when answering [SO: Zoom functionality using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710623/7478597).)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: While thinking again about your issue, I got another idea as well: If your scene is smaller than the view, it's auto-aligned. ([QGraphicsView::alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop)) In my answer, I started with zoom-in, to prevent this issue but didn't consider this further. To prevent this, you could tweak the scene size by setting [QGraphicsView::sceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took my old sample from [**SO: Zoom functionality using Qt**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710623/7478597) and added the code to pan the contents by mouse dragging:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

// class for widget to demonstrate zooming
class Canvas: public QGraphicsView {

  // variables:
  private:
    // start position for pan
    QPoint _posRMB;

  // methods:
  public: 
    // constructor.
    Canvas() = default;
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Canvas() = default;
    // disabled:
    Canvas(const Canvas&) = delete;
    Canvas& operator=(const Canvas&) = delete;

  protected:

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        _posRMB = pQEvent->pos();
        pQEvent->accept();
        setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);
      }
    }

    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      if (pQEvent->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        // pos() -> virtual canvas, _posRMB -> virtual canvas
        QPointF delta = mapToScene(pQEvent->pos()) - mapToScene(_posRMB);
        // modify transform matrix
        translate(delta.x(), delta.y());
        _posRMB = pQEvent->pos();
        // force update
        update();
        pQEvent->accept();
      }
    }

    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
        unsetCursor();
      }
    }

    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      //qDebug() << "Wheel Event:";
      // pos() -> virtual canvas
      QPointF pos = mapToScene(pQEvent->pos());
      // scale from wheel angle
      float delta = 1.0f + pQEvent->angleDelta().y() / 1200.0f;
      // modify transform matrix
      QTransform xform = transform();
      xform.translate(pos.x(), pos.y()); // origin to spot
      xform.scale(delta, delta); // scale
      xform.translate(-pos.x(), -pos.y()); // spot to origin
      setTransform(xform);
      // force update
      update();
      pQEvent->accept();
    }
};

QRectF toScr(QWidget *pQWidget, float x, float y, float w, float h)
{
  const int wView = pQWidget->width(), hView = pQWidget->height();
  const int s = wView < hView ? wView : hView;
  return QRectF(
    (0.5f * x + 0.5f) * s, (0.5f * y + 0.5f) * s,
    0.5f * w * s, 0.5f * h * s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  Canvas canvas;
  canvas.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
  canvas.setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag);
  canvas.resize(256, 256);
  canvas.show();
  // prepare scene
  QGraphicsScene qGScene;
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -1.0f, -1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), QColor(0x000000u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.2f, -0.2f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x00ff00u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff0000u));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0x0000ffu));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xff00ffu));
  qGScene.addRect(toScr(canvas.viewport(), 0.4f, -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.4f), QColor(0xffff00u));
  canvas.setScene(&qGScene);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: Demo Video (GIF animation)]

I struggled a while to get it running as expected until I realized that

```cpp
QPointF delta = mapToScene(pQEvent->pos() - _posRMB); // Not working!
```

isn't the same as

```cpp
QPointF delta = mapToScene(pQEvent->pos()) - mapToScene(_posRMB);
```

Additionally, it's important to disable the auto-fit-to-view of `QGraphicsView`:

```cpp
  canvas.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::NoAnchor);
```

---

While thinking again about OPs question, I became aware of another possible issue:
If the scene is smaller than the view, it's auto-aligned. (The [QGraphicsView::alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop) is involved.)

In my demo-session, I started with zoom-in, to prevent this issue.

Another option, to make the scene draggable even it's smaller than the view – the scene size can be tweaked by setting [QGraphicsView::sceneRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) explicitly.

---

While scrolling through the doc. of [QGrapicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) I noticed:

[**QGraphicsView::dragMode**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop)

> **dragMode : [DragMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#DragMode-enum)**
>
> This property holds the behavior for dragging the mouse over the scene while the left mouse button is pressed.
>
> This property defines what should happen when the user clicks on the scene background and drags the mouse (e.g., scrolling the viewport contents using a pointing hand cursor, or selecting multiple items with a rubber band). The default value, NoDrag, does nothing.
>
> This behavior only affects mouse clicks that are not handled by any item. You can define a custom behavior by creating a subclass of QGraphicsView and reimplementing mouseMoveEvent().

which I found worth to mention.

Comment: Its working, thanks a lot. You were right, my scene was smaller than view.

Comment: @yarpenzirgin Ah, OK. I add this to the answer.

Comment: I thought I marked it as an answer. Sorry for that.