# How to zoom in and out the SVG image displayed in QSvgWidget?

Tags: qt

A [similar question](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64993-QSvgWidget-in-QMdiSubWindow-how-to-zoom-the-image) was posted on QtForums a while ago by somebody else and got no answer.

Comment: I never heard about [QSvgWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgwidget.html) before and had a look out of curiosity. The intro text provides a hint to [QSvgRenderer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html) which in turn offers [QSvgRenderer::viewBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#viewBox-prop). (The first thing I would try out.) Furthermore, I found the [SVG Viewer Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-svgviewer-example.html) which uses `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsSvgItem`. At least, this should make your intention possible.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Zoom functionality using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47710623/7478597)

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found that if QSvgWidget is displayed without QScrollArea then @Scheff's Cat 's answer is correct - QSvgRenderer::viewBox should be used.

However, if QSvgWidget is displayed as a viewport of QScrollArea - simple resizing of QSvgWidget has the same effect as zooming.